# Textbox Value disapear when Dropdownlist index changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, textbox

I have a dropdownlist and a textbox which has TextMode is Password. 
Whenever dropdownlist index changed the value of textbox disappear. 
Anyone have a solution to fix this? Tks so much.

Update

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstudentstatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                onselectedindexchanged="ddlStudentstatus_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the DropDownList change event (and anything else related)?

Comment: Can you show your html and code behind?

Comment: My guess is that the dropdown change is causing a postback.  Passwords do not persist through postbacks.  If you change the textmode to Text, does the problem go away?

Comment: @Scottie yeah the with textmode : text, there's no problem
///to rae1n : My Dropdownlist doesn't has chagne event
//to namkha87 : ok

Comment: Ok tks u guys, problem solved, i only have to change AutoPostback value to False :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as an answer:

My guess is that the dropdown change is causing a postback. Passwords do not persist through postbacks.

Answer (score 3):

if you wanna have the text inside the textbox untouched when postingback, use the following in page_load:

```
 if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text.Trim())))
        {
            txtPassword.Attributes["value"] = txtPassword.Text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing autopostback value to false for the dropdown, would stop your SelectedIndexChanged event from firing. You can have a hiddenfield to store the value of the password textbox onblur, using javascript or jQuery.

```
$("#txtPassWord").blur(function()
    $("#hdnPassWord").val($("#txtPassWord").val());
});
```

And then in the SelectedIndexChange event of the dropdown, you can assign value to txtPassWord from hdnPassWord.

```
txtPassWord.Text = hdnPassWord.Value;
```

If you are not posting back on SelectedIndexChanged, there's no meaning wiring up the event on server side. So be clear, which way to go.